# Intuition of partial-ordered set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recently I've come in front of **partial ordered set**. I've read the wiki article but couldn't comprehend it especially the concept of **set together with a binary relation**. Can anyone please explain me what **partial ordered set** means?

> A partially ordered set (or poset) formalizes and generalizes the intuitive concept of an ordering, sequencing, or arrangement of the elements of a set.

What is the meaning of this statement? Please help.

Comment: Consider a group of humans : this is the *set*, and conisder the *relation* : "___ is father of ...". Not every two humans in the set a "related" but some of them are (e.g. John is father of Mary). This relation is a binary relation that partially order the set.

Comment: Totally ordered set is a set where you can order every elements somehow in a nice way (let's say $\mathbb{Z}$ is a very obvious example. Partially ordered set is a set which has some sort of order which is 'nice' but can't necessarily compare every element. For instance let's consider $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and lets say $(a,b)\leq(c,d)$ if $a\leq c$ and $b \leq d$. This ordering has nice property of refexivity anti-symmetry and transitivity but can't compare every element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, think about the natural numbers, $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}.$ I'm sure you know that given any two natural numbers $n,m,$ either $n<m,\,n=m,\,m<n$. Someone may want to generalise the notion of $<.$

We define $<$ as a relation on $\mathbb N,$ that is we define $R=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2|a<b\}$ and say that $n<m$ iff $(n,m)\in R$. This definition feels a little tauntological as I have used $<$ to define $<$ as a relation.

Consider now the set $X=\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. we might want to define some kind of "less than" relation on this set so for example we might say that $(x,y)<(x',y')$ iff $x<x'$ or $x=x', y<y'$ (here we're implicitly defining a set like $R$). After some careful thought, you should see that this is like alphabetical ordering in a dictionary.

We say that a set is ordered if there is some relation $<$ on the set that behaves like we expect so either $x<y, x=y, y<x$ and if $x<y, y<z$ then $x<z$.

The problem is that we can't always do this so there is a less strict definition:
A set is partially ordered if there is some relation $<$ on the set such that
either $x<y, y<x, x=y,$ or $x$ and $y$ are unrelated. However, we still have that $x<y,y<z\Rightarrow x<z.$

An example of a partial ordering on $X$ would be that $(x,y)<(x',y')$ iff $x^2+y^2<x'^2+y'^2$ Note that this means that the relation is not defined (for example) between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1).$

Comment: Hi sir; is ordering important in set? Isn't {4,5,6} same as {5,6,4}? If you can tell me what ordering really means, I'll be grateful.

Comment: A set is a very elementary object. On its own, there is no ordering so $\{5,6,4\}=\{4,5,6\}$. One can think of a set as a black box. You can ask if there is some specific thing in it and it says "yes" or "no". There is no additional information. A (partially) ordered set is a set with some extra information about the ordering. One usually writes it as a normal set followed by describing how elements are ordered. Ordering is just about saying what things come before other things, normally, about which things are less than others. It doesn't mean that you can write them in a list though.

Comment: So, here the order is important? Then what's the difference between sequence & set?

Comment: A sequence is a list of things. With a sequence, one can always find the first element and then the next and the next and so on. A set doesn't necessarily have a first element, even if it has a (partial) ordering, for example what's the smallest integer? Also, a sequence may have repeated terms whereas a set cannot (the information in a set is very limited)

Comment: Sir, can you please tell me what **set with a relation** mean? I know a set & relation but don't know what they together mean. Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: By "set with a relation" I merely mean a set and a relation on that set. For example we may talk about "$\mathbb N$ with the usual $<$" to mean that i'm talking about the naturals with the (usual) $<$ relatiom so that if I say $a<b$ then you know what I mean. This isn't really a problem for $\mathbb N$ but is useful if for example I said "consider $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ with $<$ defined as above" because then you would know what I mean when I say $x<y$.

Comment: So, sir, that means partial order is defined on a set having ordered pairs like $(x,y)$ as its element?  And partial order is a $\leq$ relation on a set, right? If $\forall (x,y)R(x',y') $ where $R$ is $\leq$, then it is called total order?

Comment: Can there be partial order relation other than $\leq$?

Comment: Yes. $\leq$ is just the name normally used for this relation. Any relation $R\subset X\times X$ satisfying the axioms ($\forall x,y,z\in X\quad xRy\,yRz\Rightarrow xRz$ and $\forall x,y\in X\quad xRy\Leftrightarrow x\not R y$) gives a partial ordering for $X$.

Comment: So, this is the real definition of partial order relation; it must be transitive & antisymmetric. Then, it'll be not wrong to say there are other partial order relations other than $\leq$. Everything I've asked, you replied it patiently. Thanks, sir, for all that. Actually I was looking for limsup of sequence of set; then I came across it. If I fell in any trouble, I would definitely ask for your help & of course sorry if I had bothered you:)